# Rollback in Ironpython using System.Data.SqlClient

Tags: sql, ironpython, rollback

I am unable to rollback using the following code snippet and need help:

```
import clr
import sys
clr.AddReference('System.Data')
from System.Data.SqlClient import SqlConnection, SqlParameter, SqlTransaction
conn_string = "****"
connection = SqlConnection(conn_string)
connection.Open()
createuser = connection.CreateCommand()
createuser.CommandText = "****"
try:
    reader = createuser.ExecuteReader()
    reader.Close()
except:
    reader.Rollback()
```

Thanks!

I understand now, however now I'm having a problem where its expecting a string but I cant do the parametrized values if I put the SQL query string in as the argument:

```
createuser.CommandText = "****"
createuser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", username);
usertransaction = connection.BeginTransaction(createuser)
try:
    usertransaction.Commit()
except:
    usertransaction.Rollback()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to begin a transaction using `SqlConnection.BeginTransaction()` method. You'll receive a transaction object having methods `Commit` and `Rollback`.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand.. You surely can (and should) use parameters in given scenario. Yes, `DbParameterCollection` doesn't have `AddWithValue` method, but you can call `CreateParameter` on your command, set it up (type, name, direction, value etc) and then `Add` it to command's `Parameters`. This is a bit cumbersome, but not hard at all... Or I misunderstood and you've meant something else?